# How to filter table names?

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables

messages20151
messages20152
messages20161
messages20162
messages20171

Except these, there's also another tables in database, my aim to filter table names and get only which starts with "messages"

Comment: `psql`?.. some tree in some pgadmin?.. some other client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you can use this (as SQL way)

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables   
WHERE table_schema='schema_name' and substr(table_name, 1, 8) = 'messages'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it does job, but can i use sort for result like: messages20171, messages20162 , messages20161 ...